# Is `@browser` the obligatory name for the ChromeDriver object when using Watir/Chrome?

Tags: cucumber, watir, watir-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I want to change the name of the `@browser` variable because I'm tired of typing it.

In `env.rb`:

```
before do
  @b = Watir::Browser.new :chrome 
end
```

This throws error:

`Unable to pick a platform for the provided browser or element: nil.
  nil was passed to the PageObject constructor instead of a valid browser or element object. (RuntimeError)`

```
before do
  @browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome 
end
```

works as expected.

```
@browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome
@b = @browser
```

doesn't work either. Is there any way to modify this variable name?

Comment: It would help to see the whole exception. Are you using Cheezy's Page-Object gem, which I believe that exception is coming from. If so, depending on how you are using the gem, it does have to be `@browser`. Watir itself does not care what variable name you use.

Comment: If you are creating your page objects and passing @browser (or whatever) into the new() then you should be able to call it whatever you want.  I have done this before when I was using multiple webdriver instances to drive multiple windows for a test.

Comment: @JustinKo I am using Cheezy's gem. Can you elaborate on "...depending on how you are using the gem..."? Sorry, should have added full exception. Please see edited question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, you can store your browser instance in a variable of any name. Watir-Webdriver does not care, nor does Cheezy's page objects. The initialization of the page object only cares what the actual object passed in is - ie it must be a `Watir::Browser` or `Watir::Element` (or the Selenium-WebDriver equivalents).

However, this is not true when using the `PageObject::PageFactory`. In the [`on_page` method](https://github.com/cheezy/page-object/blob/master/lib/page-object/page_factory.rb#L69-L80), and implicitly `visit_page` and `if_page`, the code is hard-coded to look for a `@browser` variable.

```
def on_page(page_class, params={:using_params => {}}, visit=false, &block)
  page_class = class_from_string(page_class) if page_class.is_a? String
  return super(page_class, params, visit, &block) unless page_class.ancestors.include? PageObject
  merged = page_class.params.merge(params[:using_params])
  page_class.instance_variable_set("@merged_params", merged) unless merged.empty?
  @current_page = page_class.new(@browser, visit)
  block.call @current_page if block
  @current_page
end
```

The initialization of the page object is always done with `@browser`. When you stored the browser instance in `@b`, it meant that `@browser` was `nil`. This then led to the exception you saw. If you want to use the `PageFactory` as written, you will need to stick to `@browser`.

If the variable really bothers you, there is always the option for monkey patching. Simply re-define the `on_page` and `on` method to use whatever variable you like. The following redefines the method to use `@b`:

```
require 'page-object'

module PageObject
  module PageFactory
    def on_page(page_class, params={:using_params => {}}, visit=false, &block)
      page_class = class_from_string(page_class) if page_class.is_a? String
      return super(page_class, params, visit, &block) unless page_class.ancestors.include? PageObject
      merged = page_class.params.merge(params[:using_params])
      page_class.instance_variable_set("@merged_params", merged) unless merged.empty?
      @current_page = page_class.new(@b, visit)
      block.call @current_page if block
      @current_page
    end
    alias_method :on, :on_page
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is somewhere else in your code.   If you run just the line you provided (after requiring watir)

```
require 'watir-webdriver'
@b = Watir::Browser.new :chrome
```

in a IRB session it will work just fine..

Some other code dependency (page objects library perhaps) needs a browser object and is expecting a specific name, is getting a nill (un-initialized) object instead and complaining.

Also, unless you want the overhead of opening and closing the browser for each test (can add a ton of time) you may want to initialize the browser earlier, such as in a before_all hook, or early in the startup of your test code.   Then just do something like clear cache and cookies in the before hook